# Проблема в переходе между экранами ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c

[image: Экран наслаивается на экран, немогу понять как убрать]

Для перехода использовал
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"success" sender:self];
Раньше это работало нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В iOS 13 поменялся стиль модального представления вью контроллеров (свойство `modalPresentationStyle`) на `UIModalPresentationAutomatic`, который в свою очередь преобразуется в `UIModalPresentationPageSheet`, что мы здесь и наблюдаем. Для возврата к предыдущему поведению можно явно присвоить прежний стиль: `vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen`. [Подробнее на английском](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e)

> Defaults to UIModalPresentationAutomatic on iOS starting in iOS 13.0, and UIModalPresentationFullScreen on previous versions. By default UIViewController resolves UIModalPresentationAutomatic to UIModalPresentationPageSheet, but other system-provided view controllers may resolve UIModalPresentationAutomatic to other concrete presentation styles.