# UIBarButtonItems предыдущего экрана видны в UINavigationBar следующего для iOS 13

Tags: swift, navigationbar, navigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Экран пушится в стек UINavigationController. В определенный момент UIBarButtonItems становятся не кликабельными. И видны батоны предыдущего экрана (если глянуть иерархию, то видно что поверх актуальных items размещена UIReplicantView c isOpaque = true и tintColor = .red. Совпадение?! Не думаю))

UINavigationBarAppearance не помогает.
Флаги isTranslucent и isOpaque - false.

Воспроизводится только для iOS 13(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**
Нашла вопрос с аналогичной проблемой
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134631/ios-13-uibarbuttonitem-not-clickable-and-overlapping-uinavigationbars-when-using

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема в переходе между экранами ViewController](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036139/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-viewcontroller)

Comment: [Смотрите тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492491/make-a-uibarbuttonitem-disappear-using-swift-ios) То что вам нужно .

Comment: @schmidt9 нет, вопрос о другом

Comment: @GlebSeredyuk нет, вопрос о другом