# как переключаться между вкладками TabBarController и передавать данные из одной в другую?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Данный код выводит модальное окно поверх основного контроллера, но при этом передаёт этому окну нужные данные. Как сделать так, что бы это окно не открывалось модально, а просто осуществлялся переход на данное окно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
let tableVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SaveTableViewController") as! SaveTableViewController
tableVC.titleText = alert.textFields![0].text ?? "Test"
tableVC.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
            
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(tableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            //self.tabBarController?.showDetailViewController(tableVC, sender: self)
            //self.present(tableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

При попытке получить контроллер из массива tabBarController?.viewControllers? и преобразования его к SaveTableViewController вываливается ошибка Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

```
let a = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as! SaveTableViewController
a.titleText = alert.textFields![0].text ?? "Test"                
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1]
```

Скажите пожалуйста, что у меня не правильно? И покажите пример, как переключаться между вкладками таббара и передавать данные из одной в другую?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема в переходе между экранами ViewController](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1036139/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-viewcontroller)

Comment: Чтобы открыть окно не модально, замените present() на show()

Comment: А что бы не открыть окно, а переключиться на другую вкладку tabbar, что на что нужно заменить?