# как переключаться между вкладками TabBarController и передавать данные из одного ViewController в другой?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uitabbar

При попытке получить контроллер из массива tabBarController?.viewControllers? и преобразования его к SaveTableViewController вываливается ошибка Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

let a = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as! SaveTableViewController
a.titleText = alert.textFields![0].text ?? "Test"
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1]
Скажите пожалуйста, что у меня не правильно? И покажите пример, как переключаться между вкладками таббара и передавать данные из одной в другую?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как переключаться между вкладками TabBarController и передавать данные из одной в другую?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162513/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-tabbarcontroller-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

Надо весь код смотреть, мало инфы, а данную ошибку попробуйте вначале сделать очистку, Product-> Clean. Но чаще Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. выпадает когда у Вас пустые референсы.